# Recyclerview item height changing when I do scroll up and down continuously

Tags: android, mobile, android-recyclerview

In one of my applications I am trying to use recyclerview to display content. My content would be like chat history(it may be a single line text or multiple lines text).To implement this I have used recyclerview with Textview height as wrap_content to adjust the height based on the content. For the first time it is loading fine. But when I do scroll up and down I am getting some extra white space for some of the items. (I strongly suspect this extra space is for earlier item height).

Ex: I have a recyclerview list having 1,2,3,4,5.. lines text in each row. When I do scroll up down continuously I am getting row/item height is changing like 1 line text item got 5 lines text space and 5 lines text item got 1 line text.

Please find my adapter code below.

```
public class ConversationMessagesAdapterNew extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
private ConversationDetailActivityNew context;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Utils utils;
private List<Message> messages = null;
private SessionManagement mSessionManage;
private int loginId = 0, attachmentsCount = 0, gifCount = 0;
private String mProfilePicId, mFname, mLname, fname = "", lname = "";
private ComposeDetails composeDetails;
private JSONArray attachmentArrayObj = new JSONArray();

public ConversationMessagesAdapterNew(ConversationDetailActivityNew context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.utils = new Utils(context);
    setHasStableIds(true);
    this.mSessionManage = new SessionManagement(context, Utils.SHARED_PREF);
    loginId = Integer.parseInt(mSessionManage.getString("userId"));
    this.mProfilePicId = mSessionManage.getString("profilePicId");
    this.mFname = mSessionManage.getString("firstName");
    this.mLname = mSessionManage.getString("lastName");
}

public void setMessages(List<Message> messagesList) {
    this.messages = messagesList;

    /*if (messagesList == null) {
        if (this.messages != null) {
            this.messages.clear();
            this.messages = null;
        }
    } else {
        if (this.messages != null && this.messages.size() > 0)
            this.messages.addAll(messagesList);
        else
            this.messages = messagesList;
    }*/
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.conversation_messages_list_row_item_longpress, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ViewHolder messagesListViewHolder = (ViewHolder) holder;
    Message message = messages.get(position);
    messagesListViewHolder.mMainLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            (context).loadMoreButtonlayout(message);
            return true;
        }
    });
    try {
        String picId = "";
        composeDetails = (context).getProfilePicId(String.valueOf(message.getSenderId()));
        if (composeDetails != null) {
            fname = composeDetails.getFristName();
            lname = composeDetails.getLastName();
        }
        if (message.getSenderId() == loginId) {
            picId = mProfilePicId;
        } else {
            //picId = ((ConversationDetailActivity)context).getProfilePicId(String.valueOf(message.getSenderId()));
            if (composeDetails != null) {
                picId = composeDetails.getProfilePicture();
                fname = composeDetails.getFristName();
                lname = composeDetails.getLastName();
            }
            mFname = fname;
            mLname = lname;
        }

        if (!picId.equals("null")) {
            messagesListViewHolder.iv_user_profile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            messagesListViewHolder.tv_lettersText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            messagesListViewHolder.mCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EFEFEF"));
            String url = String.format("%s%s", Constants.mDisplayProfilePicUrl, picId);
            Picasso.with(context).load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.user_default).into(messagesListViewHolder.iv_user_profile);
        } else {
            messagesListViewHolder.iv_user_profile.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            messagesListViewHolder.tv_lettersText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            messagesListViewHolder.mCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#77B633"));
            String name = getName(mFname, mLname);
            messagesListViewHolder.tv_lettersText.setText(name);
        }

        if (message.getMessageType().equals("OFFNETEMAIL")) {
            messagesListViewHolder.tv_sender_name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2C303E"));
        } else {
            messagesListViewHolder.tv_sender_name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#276eb6"));
        }

        String sendName = message.getSenderName();
        if (message.getMetric().getFlags().getCount() > 0 ||
                message.getMetric().getLikes().getCount() > 0) {
            if (sendName.length() > 15) {
                sendName = sendName.substring(0, 15) + "..";
            }
        } else {
            if (sendName.length() > 18) {
                sendName = sendName.substring(0, 18) + "..";
            }
        }
        messagesListViewHolder.tv_sender_name.setText(sendName);
        messagesListViewHolder.tv_created_time.setText(utils.getTimeStampByString(message.getCreatedOn()));

        String content = message.getContent();

        // Attachment parsing
        String prtnAttachment = "\\<attachment:(.*?)\\>";
        Pattern ptr = Pattern.compile(prtnAttachment);

        Matcher m = ptr.matcher(content);
        while (m.find()) {
            String[] fileStr = m.group(0).toString().split(":");
            if (fileStr.length > 0) {
                JSONObject file = new JSONObject();
                file.put("fileId", fileStr[1].toString());
                file.put("fileName", fileStr[2].toString());
                file.put("fileType", fileStr[3].toString());
                file.put("randomFileName", fileStr[4].toString());
                file.put("fileSize", fileStr[5].toString());
                attachmentArrayObj.put(file);
                attachmentsCount++;
            } else {
                //attachmentsFlag = false;
                // imageFlag = false;
                attachmentsCount = 0;
            }
        }
        // Emoji / Mentions parsing
        String ptrsEmoji = "\\<:(.*?)\\>";
        Pattern ptrEmoji = Pattern.compile(ptrsEmoji);

        Matcher em = ptrEmoji.matcher(content);
        while (em.find()) {
            String[] emojiStr = em.group(0).split(":");
            if (emojiStr.length > 0) {
                if (emojiStr[1].contains("mention-everyone")) {
                    String parsedStr = "<font color='#1F6EB7'>" + "@everyone" + "</font>";
                    content = content.replaceAll(em.group(0), parsedStr);
                } else if (emojiStr[1].contains("mention-")) {
                    String[] ms = emojiStr[1].split("-");
                    String parsedStr = "<font color='#1F6EB7'>" + "@" + ms[1] + "</font>";
                    content = content.replaceAll(em.group(0), parsedStr);
                } else {
                    String parsedStr = "&#x" + emojiStr[1];
                    content = content.replaceAll(em.group(0), parsedStr);
                }
            }
        }

        if (content.length() > 0) {
            messagesListViewHolder.tv_message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            messagesListViewHolder.tv_message.setText(Html.fromHtml(content));
        } else {
            messagesListViewHolder.tv_message.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (attachmentsCount > 0) {
            messagesListViewHolder.tv_message.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            messagesListViewHolder.mAttachLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            messagesListViewHolder.tv_attachments.setText(String.valueOf(attachmentsCount + gifCount) + " Attachments.");
            attachmentsCount = 0;
        } else {
            attachmentsCount = 0;
            messagesListViewHolder.tv_message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            messagesListViewHolder.mAttachLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // Likes and Flag sectin
        if (message.getMetric().getLikes().getCount() > 0) {
            messagesListViewHolder.iv_likes_icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            messagesListViewHolder.tv_likes_count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            messagesListViewHolder.tv_likes_count.setText(String.valueOf(message.getMetric().getLikes().getCount()));
        } else {
            messagesListViewHolder.iv_likes_icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            messagesListViewHolder.tv_likes_count.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (message.getMetric().getFlags().getCount() > 0) {
            messagesListViewHolder.iv_flag_icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            messagesListViewHolder.iv_flag_icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        messagesListViewHolder.mAttachLayout.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent attachmentIntent = new Intent(context, AttachmentsView.class);
            attachmentIntent.putExtra("contentAttachment", message.getContent());
            context.startActivity(attachmentIntent);
        });

        messagesListViewHolder.mAttachLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                (context).loadMoreButtonlayout(message);
                return true;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (messages != null && messages.size() > 0)
        return messages.size();
    else
        return 0;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    Message message = messages.get(position);
    return message.getId();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    LinearLayout mMainLayout;
    ImageView iv_user_profile, iv_likes_icon, iv_flag_icon;
    TextView tv_sender_name, tv_created_time, tv_message, tv_lettersText, tv_attachments, tv_likes_count;
    CardView mCardView;
    FrameLayout mMoreLayout;
    RelativeLayout mAttachLayout;
    View mDummyLongPressLayout;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mMainLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.longpress_layout_detailpage);

        mDummyLongPressLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.DummyLongPressLayout);

        mMoreLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_layout);

        iv_user_profile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_user_profile);

        tv_sender_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_sender_name);
        tv_sender_name.setTypeface(utils.mRobotoBold);

        tv_created_time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_created_time);
        tv_created_time.setTypeface(utils.mRobotoRegular);

        tv_message = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_message);
        tv_message.setTypeface(utils.mRobotoRegular);

        tv_lettersText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_lettersText);
        tv_lettersText.setTypeface(utils.mRobotoRegular);

        mCardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);

        mAttachLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.AttachmentsLayout);
        mAttachLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        tv_attachments = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_attachments);

        tv_likes_count = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_likes_count);
        iv_likes_icon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_like_icon);
        iv_flag_icon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_flag_icon);
    }
}

private String getName(String fname, String lname) {
    if (fname.length() > 0) {
        if (!fname.equals("null")) {
            fname = fname.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
        } else {
            fname = "";
        }
    } else {
        fname = "";
    }
    if (lname.length() > 0) {
        if (!lname.equals("null")) {
            lname = lname.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
        } else {
            lname = "";
        }
    } else {
        lname = "";
    }
    return fname + lname;
}
```

}

Comment: please post your adapter here

Comment: @AndroidUser, I have just added my adapter code. Please check it once..

Comment: add  @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return position;
        //return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

Comment: @AndroidUser Thanks for this input. It is working fine now.

Comment: @AndroidUser You saved my week ! Your comment should be elected as the answer

Comment: @AndroidUser why does this work? Doesn't this defeat the point of view types? You're essentially treating each position as its own view type, which will break down if items can move between positions.